# Finder not showing toolbar and sidebar sometimes

Tags: macos, finder, dock

I'm running OS X 10.8.2 with TotalFinder.

Recently, when launching Finder from *dock stacks*—for instance, the *Downloads* folder—by clicking the "Open in Finder", the toolbar and sidebar are both hidden (I have them visible by default).

I can't find an option for that. Is this a bug?

Comment: When this happens what is the state of `Show/Hide Sidebar` in the view menu?

Comment: @Diago Of course it is `Show Sidebar`. There is no problem showing sidebar and toolbar again. And a new tab would be with toolbar and sidebar. (Oops I forgot to mention that I also use TotalFinder.)

Comment: Anyway, I tested again and reproduce exactly the same problem without TotalFinder running. Seems that this is not a problem with TotalFinder (I've also tried repairing permissions).

Comment: I have had similar instances. WHen opening Finder in a certain sequence, it doesn't show the Sidebar. I actually don't even think it's a bug but the way Finder works. I also use TotalFinder, but it doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: @Diago If my memory works well, this problem hit me before several times, but recently it has become a routine, which is really frustrating—I don't even want to keep the dock stacks anymore, and I don't think it is how Finder is supposed to work. Yeah I believe the problem is on Apple's side—TotalFinder is a good add-on. I know a few other bugs about Finder (or general appleeventsd) and nothing is due to TotalFinder.

Answer (score 7):

You should check, if you have `View -> Show Toolbar` option enabled. When toolbar is disabled, there's no option to have sidebar and "Show Sidebar" option in Finder Menu `View -> Show Sidebar` is grayed out.

Worked for me.

Comment: Well, if you look at the comments below the question closely, you could find out that I have no problem re-showing sidebar or toolbar. Your answer is the fix for another problem (which I happened to have encountered ages ago). Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: +1: regardless of the OP reaction, your answer did work for me, so thanks.

Comment: It's extremely annoying that the sidebar can only be shown if the toolbar is also shown. They have completely different functionality and don't relate to each other's layout whatsoever! One is a list of shortcuts to directories/paths, and one is a toolbar for actions, all of which can be performed by keyboard shortcuts or right-click context menus. It's so infurating!

Answer (score 2):

The key command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: Strangely, this is what helped me :-)

Comment: For later versions of macOS, it's now `⌘ Command` + `⌥ Opt` + `T` as pointed out by @lyma.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer from [@chriliman](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111412/169118) is out of date.

As of MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) the command is now <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

**Disclaimer:** I do have a lot of tweaks installed, so it's *possible* that I've remapped the original keybinding

Comment: You are right - on macOS Mojave too, only `⌘ Command` + `⌥ Opt` + `T` works.

Answer (score 1):

There used to always be the little curved button in the upper-right that would let you hide/show the side bar.

Linking the two -- toolbar and side bar is odd -- and stranger yet, only one, the toolbar, can be toggled.  Hence, you can have toolbar and no side bar, but you cannot hide the toolbar and show the side bar.

The biggest problem is that the solution is buried and counter-intuitive.  The show sidebar option should always be there -- even if it were to automatically show the toolbar, too!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by restarting Finder (there was an option to do it inside TotalFinder, but now it's appeared after I restarted.). Restarting OS X should fix it tho.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Finder fixed it for me. Use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Option ^</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the dialog to kill applications. If you select the Finder (last in the list), you can access Relaunch.

The above worked for me.